# Updating a DP when needed in view rather than on change

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Say, for instance, that I have a combobox whose itemsSource is bound to a dependency property. The bound list values can change depending on many factors. Calculating those values requires a non-trivial amount of time therefore I do not want the application to update the collection unless necessary. What is the correct way in MVVM to 'lazily' update a bound property only when the data is required in the view (i.e. when the combobox is dropping down)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a method to the `ViewModel`:

```
class ViewModel {
    public void Refresh() {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

... and call it when necessary in your control.

```
class Control : UserControl {
    private ViewModel ViewModel = new ViewModel();

    void OnDropDown() {
        ViewModel.Refresh();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you that makes sense, and is what I was leaning towards. That said the OnDropDown msdn reference does not say 'when' the event is triggered. Do you know if it is before or after the dropdown has dropped? There is no previewDropDown event.

Comment: @ach -- Not sure, but you could try capturing the MouseDown event instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your ViewModel should be aware of all bound data on the screen so it's your viewmodel that will somehow fetch the data for the dropdown.

What triggers that fetch is usually a "command" in your ViewModel which usually comes from a button click or any other view event.